# Asus Notebook X53SV -SX178V new Mainboard

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply

I need a new mainbord for my Asus Notebook X53SV-SX178V, because the DC jack is broken and the mainboard is partly cracked.

So I want to order a new mainboard which is called K53SV. There exist different revisions:

- 2.1
- 2.3
- 3.0
- 3.1

Which is the difference between those revisions and which should i buy? The current mainboard revision in the notebook is `2.1`.

Comment: Have you considered contacting the ASUS support team? They may be able to help you better.

Comment: @RubyJunk: The laptop is no longer in support period. But there are some vendors on the Internet that offer it. I would be performing the installation myself.

Asus is certainly answers that only the same board fits, but is it really so?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, sorry. I meant that the ASUS support team may be able to send you a replacement, even if you had to pay them for it. And, if the current revision in the notebook is 2.1, I'd recommend you get that. Notebooks aren't very flexible when it comes to replacing parts, and honestly, nobody really knows if others would fit. As I said, the only people who would know are the ASUS support.

Comment: I know that it is a very difficult question. But of course I hope to get the best solution. Errors can be resolved within in the new revision. They could be incompatible but they do not have to be.

Comment: @RubyJunk: Asus Support can not answer my question.

Comment: You may be able to talk to some of the third party parts suppliers.  At least when it comes to server hardware, I have dealt with such a company before, and they were fairly knowledgeable about their products.  It's *possible* that their sales people know more about the hardware than anyone that you are likely to get on the phone at Asus.